# Add AutoPostBack to RadioButton in Gridview that is inserted as a literal

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

I have a gridview with a RadioButton column, which I am creating as per the following article:

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs

The gridview code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCounts" runat="server" Width="400px" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        cssClass="Grid" OnRowCreated="gvCounts_RowCreated">            
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="RadioButtonMarkup" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subcategory" HeaderText="Subcategory" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Count" HeaderText="Count" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And the back-end code is:

```
 protected void gvCounts_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Literal output = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("RadioButtonMarkup");
            output.Text = string.Format(@"<input type='radio' name='CategoryGroup' id='RowSelector{0}' value='{0}' />", e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```

However - I want the form to Post Back every time the radio button is changed, as opposed to having to click a button to "submit".

As the radio buttons here are not .net controls, but standard HTML radio buttons, I'm not sure how I can do this.

Comment: Why not replace the literal control with a RadioButton control?

Comment: the problem I had using a RadioButton control was that they weren't working as a group, as each RadioButton had a different name generated.

Answer (score 0):

An asp.net radio button renders like this in the browser:

`<input id="RadioButton1" type="radio" name="RadioButton1" value="RadioButton1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RadioButton1\',\'\')', 0)" />`

All you have to do is replicate it.  :)

Comment: This is not ideal- you will have to determine the correct ID of the radio button control (it will be generated as it is a child of a INamingContainer- the DataGrid control). While determining the ID is not particularly tricky, you are making things overly complex by doing things like this. Additionally, as no server based control exists no control will be able to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue myself (and was using the same tutorial).  If you use jquery, my solution might work for you.  In the rowCreated function I have this:

```
int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
Literal output = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("RadioButtonMarkip");
output.Text=string.Format("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Default_Group\" " +   "id=\"RowSelector{0}\" value=\"{0}\" ", e.Row.RowIndex); 

//check radio button if selected before
if (DefaultSeletectedIndex == e.Row.RowIndex || (!Page.IsPostBack && e.Row.RowIndex==0))
{
 output.Text += "checked=\"checked\"";
}

output.Text += "onclick = \"jQuery.fn.post_Default("+index+")\" />";
```

Then on the JS side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.post_Default=function(){
$.post("YourPage.aspx", {Default: arguments[0]});
};
</script>
```

Now all you need is the page load to check Request.Form["Default"] for the index value of your checked radio button.  This may not be the most elegant way of doing it, but so far its working.  I am also toying with the idea of just using jquery's $.ajax function to do it.  I think that might be a bit cleaner, but for now this works.

Answer (score 0):

> Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gvCounts.DataSource = new SupplierRepository().GetSupplierList();
            gvCounts.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string targetCtrl = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");

            **// your method, do exactly what button click did
            ShowDetails();**
        }
    }
    protected void gvCounts_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Literal output = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("RadioButtonMarkup");
            output.Text = string.Format("<input type='radio' name='CategoryGroup' onclick='__doPostBack(\"RowSelector{0}\",\"\")' id='RowSelector{0}' value='{0}'  />", e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
```